# Loading data from Firebase into a DropdownButton

Tags: firebase, flutter, dropdownlist

Soy nuevo en Flutter con Firebase y estoy intentado cargar unos arrays almacenados en Firebase en un `DropdownButton`.

Esta parte del código funcion cuando la llamo desde un botón. Devuelve una lista de bebidas que puedo imprimir por pantalla:

```
Future<List<String>> get drinks async {
    QuerySnapshot docs = await _constantes.getDocuments();
    List<String> res = List();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> datos = List();

    for (var d in docs.documents) {
      datos.add(d.data);
    }

    for (var d in datos[0]['drinks'].toList()) {
      res.add(d.toString());
    }

    return res;
  }
```

Pero mi problema es que me gustaría cargar esta lista en un `DropdownButton`, para que el usuario pueda elegir una de las bebidas cuando la aplicación le muestre el formulario:

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
            hint: Text('Choose a drink'),
            value: _currentDrink ?? 'Water',
            items: _db.drinks.then((drinks) {
              List<DropdownMenuItem> datos = List();

              for (var d in drinks) {
                datos.add(DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: d,
                  child: Text(d),
                ));
              }
              return datos;
            }),
            onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentDrink = val),
          ),
```

Pero no funciona porque  el resultado es un `Future`. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Podrías hacer esto:

Declara una variable para los valores del dropdown:

```
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItems;
```

Entonces puedes cambiar tu función asíncrona a esto y llamarlo desde `initState`:

```
drinks() async {
    QuerySnapshot docs = await _constantes.getDocuments();
    List<String> res = List();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> datos = List();

    for (var d in docs.documents) {
      datos.add(d.data);
    }

    for (var d in datos[0]['drinks'].toList()) {]
      _dropDownMenuItems.add(new DropdownMenuItem(
          value: d.toString(), child: new Text(d.toString())));
    }

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Y tu widget sería así:

```
 DropdownButton(
   value: _currentDrink ?? 'Water',
   items: _dropDownMenuItems,
   onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentDrink = val),
)
```